# Use static JSON file after build on create-react-app

Tags: reactjs, webpack, create-react-app

I'm writing a [create-react-app](https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app) web app that's going to be deployed for different customers, different domains, with the same code base, changing only a JSON config file to customize the title, labels, theme, etc.

The problem is when I build, the *config.json* doesn't exist in the *build* folder (probably due to Webpack's bundle). This means I can't simply change the config file on a built app, making it difficult to deploy to multiple domains.

Is there a way to make my `config.json` so it doesn't disappear after building?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Putting your config.json in the public folder before building will copy it to '/build/config.json'.

However the 'public/manifest.json' file is already copied in the build and holds environment variables such as {"short_name": "React App"}. I would consider moving the config options to the 'public/manifest.json' file.

Alternatively, you could use a modified copy of the build script see:'node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/build.js'. I made some quick edits to get you started:

```
// @remove-on-eject-begin
/**
 * Copyright (c) 2015-present, Facebook, Inc.
 *
 * This source code is licensed under the MIT license found in the
 * LICENSE file in the root directory of this source tree.
 */
// @remove-on-eject-end
'use strict';

// Do this as the first thing so that any code reading it knows the right env.
process.env.BABEL_ENV = 'production';
process.env.NODE_ENV = 'production';

// Makes the script crash on unhandled rejections instead of silently
// ignoring them. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will
// terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
process.on('unhandledRejection', err => {
  throw err;
});

// Ensure environment variables are read.
require('../config/env');
// @remove-on-eject-begin
// Do the preflight checks (only happens before eject).
const verifyPackageTree = require('./utils/verifyPackageTree');
if (process.env.SKIP_PREFLIGHT_CHECK !== 'true') {
  verifyPackageTree();
}
const verifyTypeScriptSetup = require('./utils/verifyTypeScriptSetup');
verifyTypeScriptSetup();
// @remove-on-eject-end

const path = require('path');
const chalk = require('react-dev-utils/chalk');
const fs = require('fs-extra');
const webpack = require('webpack');
const configFactory = require('../config/webpack.config');
const paths = require('../config/paths');
const checkRequiredFiles = require('react-dev-utils/checkRequiredFiles');
const formatWebpackMessages = require('react-dev-utils/formatWebpackMessages');
const printHostingInstructions = require('react-dev-utils/printHostingInstructions');
const FileSizeReporter = require('react-dev-utils/FileSizeReporter');
const printBuildError = require('react-dev-utils/printBuildError');

const measureFileSizesBeforeBuild =
  FileSizeReporter.measureFileSizesBeforeBuild;
const printFileSizesAfterBuild = FileSizeReporter.printFileSizesAfterBuild;
const useYarn = fs.existsSync(paths.yarnLockFile);

// These sizes are pretty large. We'll warn for bundles exceeding them.
const WARN_AFTER_BUNDLE_GZIP_SIZE = 512 * 1024;
const WARN_AFTER_CHUNK_GZIP_SIZE = 1024 * 1024;

const isInteractive = process.stdout.isTTY;

// Warn and crash if required files are missing
if (!checkRequiredFiles([paths.appHtml, paths.appIndexJs])) {
  process.exit(1);
}

// Generate configuration
const config = configFactory('production');

// We require that you explicitly set browsers and do not fall back to
// browserslist defaults.
const { checkBrowsers } = require('react-dev-utils/browsersHelper');
checkBrowsers(paths.appPath, isInteractive)
  .then(() => {
    // First, read the current file sizes in build directory.
    // This lets us display how much they changed later.
    return measureFileSizesBeforeBuild(paths.appBuild);
  })
  .then(previousFileSizes => {
    // Remove all content but keep the directory so that
    // if you're in it, you don't end up in Trash
    fs.emptyDirSync(paths.appBuild);
    // Merge with the public folder
    copyPublicFolder();
    // Copy the config file
    copyConfigJson();
    // Start the webpack build
    return build(previousFileSizes);
  })
  .then(
    ({ stats, previousFileSizes, warnings }) => {
      if (warnings.length) {
        console.log(chalk.yellow('Compiled with warnings.\n'));
        console.log(warnings.join('\n\n'));
        console.log(
          '\nSearch for the ' +
            chalk.underline(chalk.yellow('keywords')) +
            ' to learn more about each warning.'
        );
        console.log(
          'To ignore, add ' +
            chalk.cyan('// eslint-disable-next-line') +
            ' to the line before.\n'
        );
      } else {
        console.log(chalk.green('Compiled successfully.\n'));
      }

      console.log('File sizes after gzip:\n');
      printFileSizesAfterBuild(
        stats,
        previousFileSizes,
        paths.appBuild,
        WARN_AFTER_BUNDLE_GZIP_SIZE,
        WARN_AFTER_CHUNK_GZIP_SIZE
      );
      console.log();

      const appPackage = require(paths.appPackageJson);
      const publicUrl = paths.publicUrl;
      const publicPath = config.output.publicPath;
      const buildFolder = path.relative(process.cwd(), paths.appBuild);
      printHostingInstructions(
        appPackage,
        publicUrl,
        publicPath,
        buildFolder,
        useYarn
      );
    },
    err => {
      console.log(chalk.red('Failed to compile.\n'));
      printBuildError(err);
      process.exit(1);
    }
  )
  .catch(err => {
    if (err && err.message) {
      console.log(err.message);
    }
    process.exit(1);
  });

// Create the production build and print the deployment instructions.
function build(previousFileSizes) {
  // We used to support resolving modules according to `NODE_PATH`.
  // This now has been deprecated in favor of jsconfig/tsconfig.json
  // This lets you use absolute paths in imports inside large monorepos:
  if (process.env.NODE_PATH) {
    console.log(
      chalk.yellow(
        'Setting NODE_PATH to resolve modules absolutely has been deprecated in favor of setting baseUrl in jsconfig.json (or tsconfig.json if you are using TypeScript) and will be removed in a future major release of create-react-app.'
      )
    );
    console.log();
  }

  console.log('Creating an optimized production build...');

  const compiler = webpack(config);
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    compiler.run((err, stats) => {
      let messages;
      if (err) {
        if (!err.message) {
          return reject(err);
        }
        messages = formatWebpackMessages({
          errors: [err.message],
          warnings: [],
        });
      } else {
        messages = formatWebpackMessages(
          stats.toJson({ all: false, warnings: true, errors: true })
        );
      }
      if (messages.errors.length) {
        // Only keep the first error. Others are often indicative
        // of the same problem, but confuse the reader with noise.
        if (messages.errors.length > 1) {
          messages.errors.length = 1;
        }
        return reject(new Error(messages.errors.join('\n\n')));
      }
      if (
        process.env.CI &&
        (typeof process.env.CI !== 'string' ||
          process.env.CI.toLowerCase() !== 'false') &&
        messages.warnings.length
      ) {
        console.log(
          chalk.yellow(
            '\nTreating warnings as errors because process.env.CI = true.\n' +
              'Most CI servers set it automatically.\n'
          )
        );
        return reject(new Error(messages.warnings.join('\n\n')));
      }

      return resolve({
        stats,
        previousFileSizes,
        warnings: messages.warnings,
      });
    });
  });
}

function copyPublicFolder() {
  fs.copySync(paths.appPublic, paths.appBuild, {
    dereference: true,
    filter: file => file !== paths.appHtml,
  });
}

// CUSTOM FUNCTION TO COPY CONFIG.JSON
function copyConfigJson() {
    fs.copy(
        path.resolve(paths.appPath, PATH_TO_CONFIG),
        path.resolve(paths.appBuild, PATH_TO_DESTINATION),
        {dereference: true},
    });
}
```